# How to call a local variable within a broader local variable containing a list?

Tags: netlogo

I want a local variable to be updated within a broader list variable during a specific procedure in NetLogo. This is a simple version of my problem:

```
to procedure 
  let num_var 7
  let list_var [ 0 1 0 num_var ]
end
```

If I try to execute this procedure, NetLogo sends me the following error message: *expected a literal value*. Which would be the right way to call the first local variable within the broader list?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `list` instead of `[]`. The later only works with numbers, string and other lists, not with reporters. The list entry in the Netlogo Programming guide explains it nicely as well. https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists

Don't forget to include brackets with using `list`, otherwise it tries making a list of exactly 2 items.

```
to procedure 
  let num_var 7
  let list_var (list 0 1 0 num_var)
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Using list solved the problem. I was implementing a mixed-linear programming problem using the lpsolver extension. Since the example provided with the extension files used [] instead of list, I just though it wasn't possible, but it went well.